# Why the dependencies in actionlib tutorial include "roslib"?

Tags: ros, roslib, actionlib-tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the introductary tutorial of actionlib package, the sand-box package is created with the dependency roslib. I check up the introduction of roslib package and realize that "roslib contains the definition of the ros::Time and ros::Duration objects used in roscpp and other ROS C++ libraries".

Then I opened a package, wrote a program, utilizing of the ros::Time and ros::Duration without the dependency of roslib. However it worked successfully.

Thus I'm wondering why the dependencies in actionlib tutorial include roslib.

Thanks for answering.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/27728/why-the-dependencies-in-actionlib-tutorial-include-%22roslib%22?/) by [Mchaiiann](https://answers.ros.org/users/1388/mchaiiann/) on ROS Answers with karma: 130 on 2012-02-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

roslib also contains python code.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2012-02-26**:
Is roslib not a library which implement ros::Time and ros::Duration? It seems we do not have to include that when we use ros::Time and ros::Duration. Thank you~

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-02-26**:
roslib is used for c++ and python. The wiki page explains this in more detail: http://www.ros.org/wiki/roslib

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2012-02-26**:
I have seen this page before, and I found that I didn't notice roscpp and rospy use different way to run roslib. Thank you for this hint.